# Firebase, Storing snapshot datas to an array variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I use `ref.child('user').on('child_added',function())` to store what's inside a user to an array variable.

So this is my example,

```
$scope.samplearray = [];
ref.child('user').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  $scope.samplearray.name = snapshot.val().name;
  $scope.samplearray.age = snapshot.val().age;
});
```

then use that array to display it in my html using `ng-repeat`

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child events in the Firebase Database are fired asynchronously, which is a problem out of the box in Angular 1.x. You will either need to to trigger the `$digest` loop directly after adding to the array or use AngularFire. **[I recommend you use AngularFire.](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire)**

**Vanilla SDK approach**

```
function MyController($scope) {
  var ref = firebase.database.ref('items');
  var items = [];
  ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
      var item = snap.val();
      // use a super private property to keep around the key
      item.__key = snap.key; 
      items.push(item);
    });
  });
}
```

**AngularFire approach**

```
function MyController($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = firebase.database.ref('items');
  // Handles all child events: added, removed, changed, moved
  $scope.items = $firebaseArray(ref);
}
```